# TableView Layout Issues in IOS

Tags: ios, layout, ios7, ios6

**Layout Issues**
I am experiencing a Layout issues in iOS. I design a layout it working correctly on iOS 6 on both (3.5 inch) and (4 inch) devices but its subviews position changes when runs in iOS 7 on both (3.5 inch) and (4 inch).

I know the difference between iOS 6 and iOS 7 but how can i fix it through interface builder.

Comment: put some code or screen shot links so we can find the issue

Comment: I achieved it through interface builder setting . by fixing the table view. thanks to all